# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS - Randomly Restarts

Tags: boot, hardware, restart

It restarted about 3-4 times in the space of 3-4 restart attempts.

It's a dual boot, and I use Ubuntu 85% of the time. Every time i got to the same point when ubuntu was loading (after I typed in my user name and password) then it restarted. At other times, it restarts randomly, even when not booting, but that is rare (once every week or so). This starting to become a very worrying problem. Was seeking some assistance from more knowledgeable people. Am concerned that it's a hard ware problem! Eeek!

```
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
31.3 GiB
Intel® Core™ i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 12 
NV134
3.28.2
64-bit
210.5 GB

tail -f /var/log/syslog
Mar  6 16:36:10 koshy-System-Product-Name colord[1352]: failed to get session [pid 4355]: No data available
Mar  6 16:36:10 koshy-System-Product-Name rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.32.0" x-pid="1299" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Mar  6 16:36:34 koshy-System-Product-Name rtkit-daemon[1652]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Mar  6 16:36:34 koshy-System-Product-Name rtkit-daemon[1652]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Mar  6 16:37:13 koshy-System-Product-Name anacron[1268]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Mar  6 16:37:13 koshy-System-Product-Name anacron[1268]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Mar  6 16:37:20 koshy-System-Product-Name rtkit-daemon[1652]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Mar  6 16:37:55 koshy-System-Product-Name rtkit-daemon[1652]: message repeated 7 times: [ Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.]
Mar  6 16:37:55 koshy-System-Product-Name rtkit-daemon[1652]: Successfully made thread 4581 of process 2784 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Mar  6 16:37:55 koshy-System-Product-Name rtkit-daemon[1652]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.



koshy@koshy-System-Product-Name:~$ last reboot
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-88-generi Sat Mar  7 03:31   still running
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-88-generi Fri Mar  6 08:07 - 14:49  (06:42)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-88-generi Fri Mar  6 00:21 - 16:32  (-7:48)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-88-generi Thu Mar  5 09:01 - 11:32  (02:31)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-88-generi Wed Mar  4 18:19 - 18:19  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-88-generi Wed Mar  4 17:27 - 18:19  (00:52)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-88-generi Wed Mar  4 17:12 - 17:25  (00:12)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-88-generi Wed Mar  4 09:43 - 17:25  (07:41)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-88-generi Tue Mar  3 11:03 - 17:25 (1+06:21)

wtmp begins Mon Mar  2 08:30:26 2020
```

Here are my system specs: https://gist.github.com/BKSpurgeon/3314c608d4f73be7e3a596f4413e80cb

if you need further logs, please do let me know  and I will provide it.

Thank you!

Comment: Your issue sounds like hardware to me (which is off-topic), have you run a memtest through a few times, checked your motherboard for swollen caps, or looked at the reliability of your PSU?  *If it's a enterprise server, some clues may exist in hardware logs too*

Comment: thx mate - i will take your advice. i haven't (heard) of memtest but will do one. also would you know where i can post re: hard ware issues?

Comment: To run memtest, I'd boot a 'live' system (such as Ubuntu install media) and select the option there.  Your system likely has it installed already which can be used if you select it at `grub`.

Comment: Since you have two operating systems on the PC, does this problem occur with the other operating system booted? That's the best way to determine if this is a hardware or OS issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now there are two things that can happen here:

1. Ubuntu restarts by properly shutting down the way you normally shut down by pressing power off -> shut down. You will see services shutting down and eventually computer shutting down. In that case the problem is a software issue and should be addressed. In that case submit a bug as described in another thread:
   https://askubuntu.com/a/5126/329836
2. whole computer shuts down immediately. This is related to hardware issue. There are three often causes of it:

a) already mentioned memory issues. to confirm, check with memtest.

b) PSU issues. It's hard to diagnose this without proper measurement tools, but when your PSU cannot provide enough power, or doesn't supply it consistently, the computer will not be able to process and will terminate. Please try with another power PSU cable first, this fails the most often. Then try with another power supply unit that provides enough power. I must admint, I had issues with "Bronze" PSU but never had issues with "Gold" or "Platinum" ones (yet!) although they are more pricey

c) a motherboard issue - if the memory tests and psu replacement fails it might be worth to submit this to your motherboard vendor. Sometimes such issues can be caused by wrong BIOS or components, and they will know what to do about it. (usually either bios upgrade or MOBO replacement)